# Proper non-string Javascript exceptions

Tags: javascript, exception, ecmascript-5

Somehow this does not feel like the culmination of the 50 years programming language development:

```
  throw "My exception message here";
```

What's the correct way to do exceptions in Javascript, so that

- They can be identified (instanceof)
- They can carry other payload besides the default message and stack trace
- They "subclass" base Exception, so that debug console and such can extract meaningful information about the exception
- Possible nested exceptions (converting exception to another): if you need to catch an exception and rethrow new one the orignal stack trace would be preserved and could be meaningfully read by debugging tools
- They follow Javascript best practices

Comment: JavaScript really doesn't have these? Can you serialize any object to string in JS?

Comment: @VladislavZorov: Yes, Javascript has these.

Comment: Clarified the need for nested exceptions

Comment: Love the beginning of the question. Any talk about JavaScript should start like that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`throw new Error("message");`

or if you want to be more specific use one of the [Error Objects](http://es5.github.com/#x15.11)

It's important to make sure you throw real errors because they contain the stack trace. Throwing a string is stupid because it doesn't have any meta data attached to it.

You can also subclass errors

```
// for some sensible implementation of extend 
// https://gist.github.com/1441105#file_1pd.js
var MyError = extend(Object.create(Error.prototype), {
   ...
});
```

Comment: "for some sensible implementation of extend" what? I don't get it.

Comment: Javascript extend object pattern is a common design pattern implemented by many Javascript frameworks e.g. jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: @Mikko: Yeah, I know, but I don't get that sentence. Isn't there something missing?

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark It's a disclaimer saying I expect some sensible implementation of extend to exist in the environment. Also LOL @ extend being a design pattern. It's a utility function -.-

Comment: I'd say extend is a pattern, as it is commonly exploited in many prototypish ways and not limited to one library / function. Some frameworks call extend() function something else, too.

Comment: The Error Objects definition within the anotated ES5 source now resides at http://es5.github.io/#x15.11

Answer (score 9):

A base "exception" in JavaScript is built-in `Error` object:

```
throw new Error("My exception message here");
```

You can define your custom exceptions as:

```
function CustomError(message) {
  this.message = message;
}

CustomError.prototype = new Error();
CustomError.prototype.constructor = CustomError;
```

Check for exception type with `instanceof`. There is also a [handy list of built-in exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Error_types).

Comment: Avoid calling `new Error` in your `CustomError` assignment as it invokes the constructor on `CustomError` leaving stack trace data behind. Favour using Prototypical extension instead (`CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error);`)

Comment: @Raynos Why do you use Object.create(Error) instead of new Error? Could you clarify the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it, and satisfy the question requirements.

Why?

The problem is getting the stack. Native error object (NativeError from now on), initializes the stack when its constructor is called. To get the stack in MyError (your error subclass), you have to call the NativeConstructor inside MyError's constructor. So, your MyError class looks something like this:

```
function MyError(msg) {
    Error.call(this, msg);
}
```

But, this does not work. Because according to [HTML5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.11.1) spec:

"if you call Error as a function, it returns a new Error object".

Instead of Error's constructor being nice and initializing your custom error class, it creates an error object that you have no use for. I haven't found a way to call NativeError constructor and have it initialize MyError subclass.

Not all is lost.

If we relax the original question requirements, and forget about "instanceof" to test exception class (so Java anyway), and use "name" instead, it can be done. Just declare MyError as:

```
function MyError(msg, customArg) {
    var e = new Error(msg);
    e.name = "MyError";
    e.custom = customArg;
    return e;
}
```

This is what I do. Instead of switching on "instanceof", switch on "name" instead.

Comment: Not all libraries respect the `name` variable. [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html) for example requires a custom error `prototype` to descend from `Error.prototype`. In fact depending on sate of an object can run you into trouble if your not 100% careful since name can be mutated while relying on a prototype chain is less fragile and more OOP idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `Error` object by calling the [`Error` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).
An `error` object can have a message and a name. When catching you can check for a specific name or you can create a custom Error Type by inheriting the `Error` prototype. This allows the use of `instanceof` to differ between different Error types.

```
// Create a new object, that prototypally inherits from the Error constructor.  
function MyError(message) {  
    this.message = message || "Default Message";  
}  
MyError.prototype = new Error();  
MyError.prototype.constructor = MyError;  

try {  
    throw new MyError();  
} catch (e) {  
    console.log(e.name);     // "MyError"  
    console.log(e.message);  // "Default Message"  
}  

try {  
    throw new MyError("custom message");  
} catch (e) {  
    console.log(e.name);     // "MyError"  
    console.log(e.message);  // "custom message"  
}
```

Example taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: Avoid `x.prototype = new y();` favour `x.prototype = Object.create(y.prototype)`

Comment: @Raynos In a browser environment `Object.create` might not be available and you'd need a polyfill. In a JavaScript >= 1.8.5 environment I agree.

Comment: it is still better to polyfill Object.create then to use `new y();`

Comment: The polyfill offered by developer.mozilla.org is just `x.prototype = y.prototype`.  Wouldn't that create a reference?

Comment: @Eliasdx: `x.prototype = y.prototype` does not do what you want (that is, set x.ptototype to an empty object that inherits from y.prototype). Check again.